# Object property and object prototype

Tags: javascript

**EDITED**

What is the difference in doing:

```
var a = function(){};
a.myProperty = function(){};
```

Versus:

```
var a = function(){};
a.prototype.myProperty = function(){};
```

I realise this might be a silly or vague question but what do I need to understand to know the difference between the two and when to use one over the other?

Comment: Objects don't have `.prototype` but functions do. The latter code will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the question has been heavily edited since it was first posed, which is why the existing comment and answer make no sense.

All functions have prototypes. The methods attached to these prototypes are available to instances of objects created by calling the function as a constructor. So in the second example, if you write `var o = new a();` then you will be able to invoke `o.myProperty();`.

Additionally all functions are objects, so you can set arbitrary properties directly on the function itself, as per the first example. You can also access the function from the object using `o.constructor` (or `this.constructor` from a member function). This could be used to implement the equivalent of C++ static class variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Your setting a property on an object.

Note that your second example fails because you havn't set `a.prototype` to a value.

Of course if you made `a` a function then it gets a prototype property by default.

And that `.prototype` property has a special property. If you invoke `new someFunction` then the `[[Prototype]]` of the return value is `someFunction.prototype`.

This only applies if `.prototype` is a property of a function. Since `new` only works on functions.